# Visual Studio .net standard library template breaks using directive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-2.0, class-library

I'm currently trying to learn a bit about .NET and get back into programming with C#. To do both I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio) official tutorial on how to create a .NET standard class library.

One of the first steps is to create a **Class Library (.NET Standard)** template provided by the .NET kit in visual studio. This creates a basic file with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace StringLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Now visual studio immediately greets me with this error message:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried google, some people have vaguely similar problems, where they forget to add the reverence to their different projects, however I cannot find any way to add *System*... Besides, the rest of the tutorial files work fine and are able to import *System*. (I can also reference the other files just fine)

Did anyone encounter a similar problem? Is the template bugged, or did I mess up installing the kit (which I did via the Visual Studio installer, so no idea, how that could happen)?

If I can clarify anything, feel free to ask, and thanks in advance.

Comment: VS 2019 installation comes with .Net Core but you don't want to use it. Make sure that the library targets .NET Standard instead. Right-click on the library project in `Solution Explorer`, and then select `Properties`. The `Target Framework` text box should say `.NET Standard 2.0`.

Comment: Open command prompt and navigate to that project folder. Run `dotnet restore` and see what it says then.

Comment: @derloopkat Yeah, thats what the tutorial suggests, and that was already selected by default.

Comment: @LexLi This is the error I get when i use the restore function:
**error NU1101: Das Paket "NETStandard.Library" wurde nicht gefunden. Es sind keine Pakete mit dieser ID in folgenden Quellen vorhanden: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [(Project Folder Path)]**
In english it means that the package "NETStandart.Library" was not found. No packages with this ID exist in the following folders: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [(Project Folder Path)]...
I'm going to google that error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lex Li suggested, i used `dotnet restore` in the project folder and got the error NU1101, which meant, that the package I want to use could not be found.
I found this website https://www.hossambarakat.net/2020/06/24/fix-error-NU1101/ and chose option A: to add a nuget.config. To do this I opened the command prompt and navigated to `\Users\myUser\Appdata\Roaming\NuGet` and executed NuGet.Config, which opened a file in Visual Studio. Here I only added the package sources lines from the following lines, since the rest was already there (see also the link):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

After that restarting Visual Studio solved the issue, and I can now continue the tutorial.

Thanks for the help!